# How to define constraint about consecutive periods in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

In my optaplanner project i have periods with fixed duration.
For some of them there is a medium constraint that they should be scheduled in a row, occupying for example 5 directly adjacent timeslots.
I want to use Java constraints streams but dont manage to define this constraint using the timeslot-pattern.

I know that this constraint can be defined using the time-grain-pattern as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/30702865. I have done this and it works. But I want to compare timeslot-pattern to time-grain-pattern because the have different behaviour when it comes to escape local maxima. The problem with time-grain-pattern is that those 5 periods could also be sheduled in every possible partition of 5 (eg. as 2 + 2 + 1).

Has anyone a hint on how to define the constraint using timeslot-pattern?

Comment: You got any solution of this, if yes then please help me for the same.

Comment: Solved it as in the new answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using the newly added [`ifExists()` building block](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constraintStreamsConditionalPropagation). Without knowing your actual domain model, I imagine the constraint to look like this:

```
private Constraint twoConsecutivePeriods(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.from(Period.class)
            .ifExists(Period.class, equal(Period::getDay, period -> period.getDay() + 1))
            .penalize("2 consecutive periods", period -> ...);
}
```

Consequently, `ifNotExists()` may be used to achieve the opposite. We have examples of both in [Traveling Tournament OptaPlanner example](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/travelingtournament/optional/score/TravelingTournamentConstraintProvider.java).

Please note that this API is only available since OptaPlanner 7.33.0.Final onward.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using `ConstraintCollectors.toList()` as follows:

```
factory.from(Period.class).groupBy(Period::getCourse, ConstraintCollectors.toList())
                    .penalize(id, score, (course,list)->dayDistributionPenalize(course,list));
```

and

```
public int dayDistributionPenalize(Course course, List<Period> list) {
        var penalize = 0;
        var dayCodes = dayCodesFromPeriodList(list);

        for (var dayCode : dayCodes)
            if (!getAllowedDayCodes(course).contains(dayCode))
                penalize++;
        return penalize;
    }
```

Where `getAllowedDayCodes()` returns for example 0111110000, 0230000000 or 0005000000 etc. from a hash-map if a course has to have 5 consecutive periods.